# I am trying to create a custom mouse cursor that follows my mouse movement with a slight delay using nextjs14

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, event-listener

I am trying to create a custom mouse cursor that follows my mouse movement at a delayed speed in nextjs 14.

It is being temperamental and is not working 100% of the time

I am having issues due to the use client and use server functionality

I created a client wrapper in order to try get around the _layout.tsx being a server component.

```
    export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <ClientApplication>
          <Navbar />
          <div className="customPointer" />
          {children}
        </ClientApplication>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
```

}

```
'use client'
```

import { ElementRef, ReactNode } from 'react'

type Props = {
children: ReactNode
}

```
export default function ClientApplication({ children }: Props) {
  let cursorSmall: ElementRef<'div'> | null
  const positionElement = (e: MouseEvent) => {
    const mouseY = e.clientY - 60
    const mouseX = e.clientX - 10

    if (cursorSmall) {
      cursorSmall.style.transform = `translate3d(${mouseX}px, ${mouseY}px, 0) duration-500`
    }
  }
  if (typeof document !== 'undefined' && typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    cursorSmall = document.querySelector('.customPointer')
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', positionElement)
  }

  return children
}
```

It is either working perfectly or else the custom mouse is just on the page static or else not working at all